# Is there a way to copy string from cmd string?

Tags: c++, string, cmd, ping

I'm totally new to coding. I need an advice from veteran because I doing this for my part of my task.

Is there a way to read a string generated by Command Prompt (CMD)?

My task is to create a code to ping all the network and assign IP address as active and inactive through Input/output with files perhaps.

I wanted to copy a string from cmd for example:

Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64 <- (This indicate active)
Reply from 192.168.0.2: Destination host unreachable <- (This indicate inactive)

If I able to copy that line, I can write a If/Else condition to separate them. If there is any easier way to improve this scenario, please do assist me. Thank you.

The code below is to ping all IP Address until 255, but I still need 1 more function which to separate Active and Inactive IP Addresses.

```
    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
    string ipAddress;

    cout << "Enter the IPv4 address network..." << endl;
    cout << "Example: 10.0.0. or 192.168.1." << endl;

    getline(cin, ipAddress);
    cout << "Please wait..." << endl;

    string s = "ping " + ipAddress;

    for (int x = 0; x <= 255; ++x)
            {
                    stringstream ss;
                    ss << x << endl;
                    string newString = ss.str();
                    string finalString = s + newString;

                    system(finalString.c_str());
            }

    system("pause");
    }
```

P.S I also post in http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/196197/

Comment: Do you want to be able to capture the output of your `std::system()` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `popen` function. This function allow you to read the output of your command.

Like Martin say on the comment, on Windows you will use `_popen` , msdn doc :

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx)

See exemple for linux  from this page :

http://www.sw-at.com/blog/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/

Comment: That won't work for the OP.  He specifically says "CMD" which is the MS Windows command line shell.  He'll need to use `_popen` (note leading underscore), and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx is the link to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is another way to copy from the CMD.

The code below launches Windows own *ping.exe* with the built in function `system()`

`system("ping www.google.com > ping.txt ")`

and it redirects the output from the console screen into a text file

```
ping www.google.com > ping.txt
```

and stores it in a file called *ping.txt*. The file is then opened

```
//open text file ping.txt
ifstream TextFile ("ping.txt");
```

and put in a string vector and is displayed.

```
// display ping results
for (int i=0;i<LinesFromtextFile.size(); i++){
   cout<<""<< LinesFromtextFile[i] <<"";
}
```

With the contents from the pinging stored in `vector<string> LinesFromtextFile` ,  you are free to do what you want with it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>       
using namespace std;


int main () {

    int j=0;
    char *url = new char[256];
    string line;
    vector<string> LinesFromtextFile;

    memset(url,' ', sizeof(url) );
    strcpy(url, "ping www.google.com > ping.txt " );

    cout<<"\n\n"<< url <<"\n\n";

    // launch ping from visual c++
    system( url );

    //open text file ping.txt
    ifstream TextFile ("ping.txt");
    while (getline(TextFile, line)){

        // store lines from textfile into vector
        LinesFromtextFile.push_back(line);
        LinesFromtextFile[j] = LinesFromtextFile[j] +"\n";

        j++;
    }
    TextFile.close();

    // display ping results
    for (int i=0;i<LinesFromtextFile.size(); i++){
       cout<<""<< LinesFromtextFile[i] <<"";
    }
    delete[] url;


cout<<"\nPress ANY key to close.\n\n";
cin.ignore(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason don't want to use `_popen()`, there is an alternative way:
You can use `>filename` syntax to redirect the output of `ping` to a file.

For example, `std::system("ping 8.8.8.8 >out.txt")` will call the ping and write it's output to `out.txt`.

This feature is a part of the windows shell itself, thus it will work with any program.